# How do I open 2 or multiple applications using openfin

Tags: javascript, openfin

I am trying to add 2 url's to my openfin app.json so that when I click on the openfin shortcut it just pops up 2 applications?

Answer (score 0):

Include first application url and a preloadScripts in you configuration, Include child window open code for second application in preload script, as this,

```
var win = new fin.desktop.Window(
    {
        name: "secondApp",
        url: "http://second-app.com",
        defaultWidth: 600,
        defaultHeight: 400
    },
    function() {
        win.show();
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("Error creating window:", error);
    }
);
```